# In Casino Royale, why did the CIA agent had to wait?

Tags: plot-explanation, james-bond, casino-royale

In Casino Royale, the CIA agent that offers to fund Bond after he lost the first $10M says "Once you win the money, CIA is going to get Le Chiffre." Why does CIA need to wait though? What difference does it make whether or not he lost his money?

Answer (score 6):

Without the money to pay back his investors, Le Chiffre will be looking for a deal with someone else to keep him alive; almost certainly the intelligence services of a global power.

MI5 and CIA both want to bring Le Chiffre in so they can make a protection deal (against what emerges to be SPECTRE, a deal which almost certainly would have been ineffective), in exchange for the information Le Chiffre possesses *about* SPECTRE.

Comment: Though, at that time it was rather Quantum, if even that.

Comment: Quantum was a [shell organisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_organization) for SPECTRE, it was never a real thing; they just weren't allowed to say 'SPECTRE' for copyright reasons at the time. It was always SPECTRE.

Comment: I was alluding to the stand of knowledge (be that audience or MI6 knowledge) during *Casino Royale*. As much as I know (which admittedly might be wrong) Quantum did very well exist in the source material as an independent organization and reappropriating it as a sub-organization of SPECTRE was an afterthought developed for *Spectre* (the movie) during the conception of that movie. I see that in light of the new movie this is a rather academic concern, though, which is why it was just a comment.

Comment: Nah, Quantum was never in any of the books. The second Craig film takes it title from a short story, which doesn't feature any organisation. It was always just a stalling tactic until they could start using the name SPECTRE. What I'm saying is that Quantum never really existed, it was just a fake name to hide the activities of SPECTRE... I don't think Quantum was ever real.

Comment: And all I'm saying is that this isn't the case as of the in-universe knowledge present at the point of *Casino Royale* and neither does it seem to be the case that Quantum, even if only a backup strategy due to copyright problems, was intended as a sub-organization of SPECTRE before the writing of *Spectre*. Newly gained rights for SPECTRE or not, their patronage of Quantum *is* an afterthought (as much as Raoul Silva's involvement in any such larger plan is for that matter). I think I understand what you try to say, though.

Comment: //moves hands around// Your eyes are heavy. You are sleepy. You shall disregard the retcons. The retcons are bad.